# Failed to connect to all replicas when using cqlsh's COPY

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

my 3-node Cassandra cluster is deployed on AWS with a AWS elastic load balancing (ELB)

When I run the following:

```
$cqlsh -u <userid> -p <pwd>  <ELB's ip> -f backup.cqlsh
```

and in backup.cqlsh:

```
COPY comm_hub.my_table TO 'my_table.csv' WITH PAGESIZE=10;
```

but after exporting about 200 rows, I got

```
backup.cqlsh:1:
Error for (-429560303281209914, -419692349690315328):
Failed to connect to all replicas ['10.16.234.41', '10.16.233.40', '10.16.234.130'] for (-429560303281209914, -419692349690315328), errors:
['NoHostAvailable - (\'Unable to connect to any servers\', {\'10.16.234.41\': error(None, "Tried connecting to [(\'10.16.234.41\', 9042)]. Last error: timed out")})', 'NoHostAvailable - (\'Unable to connect to any servers\', {\'10.16.233.40\': error(None, "Tried connecting to [(\'10.16.233.40\', 9042)]. Last error: timed out")})', 'NoHostAvailable - (\'Unable to connect to any servers\', {\'10.16.234.130\': error(None, "Tried connecting to [(\'10.16.234.130\', 9042)]. Last error: timed out")})'] (will try again later attempt 1 of 5)
```

What I am missing?

Comment: btw, using a load balancer defeats the purpose of cassandra coordinators. see [here](http://blog.tomas.cat/en/2013/05/13/cassandra-frequent-mistakes/)

Comment: Did you try to throttle the copy command? This can be achieved using NUMPROCESSES and MAXREQUESTS. More info [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a local cluster and solved it by setting `NUMPROCESSES = 1`.

In the example you provided: `COPY comm_hub.my_table TO 'my_table.csv' WITH PAGESIZE=10 AND NUMPROCESSES=1;`